# Audacity crahed mid recording and now the exported audio recording is broken

Tags: audio, recording, audacity, recovery, crash

I started to record the audio of a meeting to listen to it later via audacity, but right at the end of the meeting my laptop shut down because the battery was dead. I immediately started my laptop back up again, and all my tabs, as well as my (paused) recording were still open. Audacity had not detected a crash. I just exported the audio and closed the session without saving the project.

Today I opened said exported audio and could only make out random noise, and sometimes sounds that gave the impression that someone was talking. My friend helped me to maybe recover the audio by checking if the meta data were the problem. He tried out different bit and sample rates but to no success. The spectogram showed that the mids are completely missing. In the attached photo you see what a typical recording looks like versus this broken one.

I would really appreciate your help, as it would be very important to me to recover this audio.[image: Spectogram of broken versus normal audio]

Comment: I very much doubt the audio can be recovered.

Comment: Hi lariiiileinchen. In what format did you record and then export it?